# How to calculate this limit by stolz theorem

Tags: limits, analysis, products

Let $f(x)$ be a positive function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}=a>0.$

The question is how to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n+1]{\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} f(k)}-\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n f(k)}.$$

I think it can be computed by Stolz Theorem. But I do not know how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Better to use the notation $f_n$ for $f(n) $ and let $g_n=\sqrt[n] {\prod_{k=1}^n f_k} $. Use Cesaro Stolz to get $g_n/\sqrt[n] {n!} \to a$ and proceed further. Please update the question with your working and let me know if any more help is required.

Comment: You will also need the result $n/\sqrt[n] {n!} \to e$.

Comment: @Singh  Thank you very much. I got it.